# Restful web service in netbeans 7.4 produces a JSON array, but i want a Json object holding the array which is created from a sql server table

Tags: java, arrays, json, netbeans

I created a web service in netbeans using "RESTful Web Services from a Database" 
. In the response i would like to return a JSON Object to hold an array of the results form the database. Currentrly the result is an JSON array

Comment: Im recieving this array [{"goals":2,"name":"W","names":"C","playerID":1},{"goals":2,"name":"W","names":"Dua","playerID":1},{"goals":2,"name":"Wi","names":"S","playerID":1}]                                                                                                    But i want it to be like this:                                                                                                     {"data":[{"goals":2,"name":"Wo","names":"Ch","playerID":1},{"goals":2,"name":"W","names":"Da","playerID":10},"goals":2,"name":"W","names":"S","playerID":3}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very simple.

Create a POJO Class with the following

```
private NewObject jsonObject;
//Getter and setter method.
```

Create a new Class with the Name "NewObject" and create a variable as below

```
private List<Stirng> databsevalues.
//Getter and setter
```

Get the values from database and put it in databsevalues (which u currently have)
Now create an object for NewObject as below and assign it.

```
NewObject  object = new NewObject ();
```

already u have the dtabsevalues in List.

do the following

```
object.set(databsevalues);
```

// will do the necessary thing

Comment: let me know if u  need futhur help

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was useful.